# Best Cocoa/Objective-C Wrapper Library for SQLite on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm developing for the iPhone and am looking for a good Cocoa/Objective-C library for working with SQLite.  I don't want to use the standard procedural SQLite C API.  I see options at [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) under the Objective-C section, but am not sure which is the best in terms of library API design, stability, and functionality.  I'd like to use something that's actively being developed and hopefully will be around for a while.  Anyone have suggestions based on experience using one?

Thanks

Comment: Core. Data. Every. Time.

Comment: currently Coredata is best option.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I personally use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), and the last update to it was yesterday.

Comment: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 12):

I'm also a fan of FMDatabase, although I've had to customize my own version of it.  My apps use a layer around it I wrote called ArchDBObject that transparently converts objects to and from a database representation; I'm thinking about releasing it in some form, but I haven't really decided how yet.

In any case, FMDatabase can be had at https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb.

Comment: Project has moved to here: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 12):

The simplest I've found is this one https://github.com/misato/SQLiteManager4iOS

SQLiteManager by Ester Sanchez.

Using it is basically like this:

```
NSArray *results = [dbManager getRowsForQuery:@"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1"];
```

`results` is an array containing dictionaries. Each dictionary is a single returned row where the keys are the names of each column in the table.

After that you can do things like this:

```
NSDictionary *aPerson = [results objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *firstName = aPerson[@"firstName"];
NSString *email = aPerson[@"email"];
```

Comment: Ok, well this looks amazing. Why aren't there any votes?

Hmmm, FMDB vs SQLiteManager4iOS ...

Comment: No idea, I don't think this one is widely used. I've tried them both and I definitely prefer the latter.

Comment: Imagine what happens for a table with 10000 rows and 10 columns with 255 characters of text each....

Comment: @Christoph If you can even come up with a single situation where you need to fetch 10000 rows at once with no filtering, I can't see why you're looking for a simple SQLite-wrapper honestly...

Comment: @Accatyyc I do not really understand your comment. I have not been looking for a SQLite wrapper - I would always go with CoreData. But I am sure loading 10000 rows with 10 columns with 255 bytes results in a 24MB memory chunk that will blow up sooner or later. Large numbers of items (contacts, images, whatever) are QA's favorite test case and it always blows up. And that was the reason for my comment; that solution is just not large number ready.

Answer (score 7):

FMDB is nice because it's the lightest way to not have to deal with the C calls and type conversions, while still giving you full access to the SQL.

The thing I generally do not like about object-relational wrappers is that you get too distant from the SQL being generated and that's when performance can start to suffer.

Answer (score 1):

I spent the last few hours looking at the options -- haven't been in production with any of these yet, so YMMV.

The lightest weight wrapper I found was here:

http://th30z.netsons.org/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper/

I don't know if it has an official name. It's just 1 class, and it abstracts the nastiness of the SQLite api, while leaving the value of working directly with SQL. The learning curve is 5 minutes, assuming you know SQL already. Since it's so small, I can imagine it would be easy to fix anything that might go wrong with it.

Comment: The URL no longer seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you could also have a look at the following repository that provides a set of classes that can be used to create SQL statements and provides a simple way to handle a SQLite database connection.  It is located at https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple ORM on top of FDBM here http://code.google.com/p/chibiorm/.

With it, you can use raw SQL when you wish, return any SQL as a dict list, or use the nice OO style.