# How To Create DataBase:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I am a fresher to Objective-C language. So i need some guidance from familiar people like you. Especially i need to know how to create a database in Objective-C with sqlite3. If any of you is interested to help, please go ahead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not really a database system, you can use [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html) framework. It allows you to save your data in a sqlite3 database.

For third-party frameworks, you can jump to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640885/best-cocoa-objective-c-wrapper-library-for-sqlite-on-iphone).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use SimpleDB created by myself. It is an easy-to-use key/value database class that does not require SQL knowledge. It can be found here: http://github.com/AaronBratcher/SimpleDB