# Is here a framework or wrapper class that makes usage of sqlite3 easier on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I wonder if someone already wrote a nice wrapper class that will make it easier to use all this "ugly" c code hacking in objective-c, like casting things around and other stuff?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640885/best-cocoa-objective-c-wrapper-library-for-sqlite-on-iphone

Answer (score 2):

[FMDB](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/source/browse/trunk/fmdb)

Comment: It doesn't come prepackaged as an iPhone framework or library - but you should be able to just drop the classes into your project and start using them.
It's also easy to turn it into a static library.

Comment: "This project currently has no downloads." ...i read that almost every time on any google code project. strange. How to get it?

Comment: +1 for FMDB. If you don't want to deal with the complexity of Core Data or you come from a strong DB background and prefer dealing with raw SQL, FMDB is awesome. Much cleaner and easier than dealing with the sqlite3 C api.

Answer (score 2):

New in IPhone SDK 3.0 is core data.  It can be used to right data to a sqlite database and manage it all for you.  I think it is more involved than just querying a table, but I think it also has added benefits like mapping table rows to your model objects.
[IPhone Core Data Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: isn't that Area 51 like NDA stuff? I don't like SDK 3.0. All the iPod touch users don't upgrade.

Comment: The NDA was lifted.  The URL is a public URL - not only for IPhone developer members.

Comment: I also think that you're mistaken in regards to upgrade rates: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/06/whats-the-uptake-on-iphone-os-30.ars .  If someone won't pay $10 for a major upgrade from Apple, they probably won't buy your product.  Everything I do is 3.0-only now.

Comment: I don't trust these stats. I know personally about 20 ipod touch users in real life, and in different countries. Only 4 of them upgraded to 3.0. The others say that they just don't need these new features so mucht to spent 10 bucks on it. They just look if they find apps that work with 2.x rather than 3.0, and they do pay a lot for apps.

Comment: I'd put my faith in a large sampling of users, rather than pure anecdotal evidence.  From my experience, not a single one of my users complained when I switched to being 3.0-only, my sales didn't decrease, and I'm reaping tremendous rewards in performance after switching from SQLite to Core Data (loading time, responsiveness, and memory).

Comment: My two cents:  We saw an obvious and sharp decline in 2.x usage as soon as 3.0 came out, using the statistics provided to us by Flurry Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

fmdb is a Cocoa / Objective-C wrapper around SQLite

You can download it here.
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

I put a link on fmdb demo / example in this issue.
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/64

fmdb.m is more of generic codes for Objective-C, not spefically for iOS. You have to delete or move fmdb.m if you can to use the library for iOS (iPhone/iPad)project. It is mentioned in the aforementioned issue (URL above).

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out from the commandLine with

```
svn checkout http://flycode.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ flycode-read-only
```

for everything or just add the name of the trunk you want.

Comment: interesting. thanks. where would the command line store all this stuff? and why does google not offer a easy download but this hacker-style svn checkout mechanism instead? i just wonder why they make it so complicated.

Comment: tried it and works. it stored the stuff somewhere on the mac, in my user dir under "flycode-read-only". I feel like a real "hacker" now ;) best way to download things!

Answer (score 0):

This is also pretty clean Wrapper Class by author of the asihttp
[egodatabase](https://github.com/pokeb/egodatabase)

regards,
Neil