# Multiple SQLite Queries on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have more than 3 views.  My database looks like this:

```
    Category:

    CatID | CatTitle
    ----------------
      1   | XYZ
      2   | Sample


    Content:
    ItemID | ItemCatID | ItemText | ItemText2 | ItemText3 | ItemText4
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
      1    |     1     |   Test   |    Bla    |  Sample   |  MoreContent
      2    |     1     |   Test2  |  BlaBla   |  Sample2  |  Other Content
      3    |     2     |   Test3  |  BlaBla2  |  Sample3  |  Other Content2
```

I want a view where first page category, second page list (ItemText), third page detail.

I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing that.  If I use JOIN should I define "sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement" in triple?

I think it can be done with 'For', "get parent,child" (like a cursor in java)?

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want.
Can you be more specific?

I can give you two tips though, first SQLite does not support stored procedures and has a very limited support for PL/SQL:http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html
if you REALLY MUST use it I suggest looking at this, I never tried it but it may work:
http://chriswolf.heroku.com/articles/2011/01/26/adding-stored-procedures-to-sqlite

Second, you usually wanna use a Wrapper around SQLite c functions so you worry about the SQL itself more and less about the c functions, examples:
[Best Cocoa/Objective-C Wrapper Library for SQLite on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640885/best-cocoa-objective-c-wrapper-library-for-sqlite-on-iphone)

Hope this helps