# How to read data from database

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Cocoa/Objective-C Wrapper Library for SQLite on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640885/best-cocoa-objective-c-wrapper-library-for-sqlite-on-iphone)

Can you please refer me how to read data from database in sqlite. I have an sqlite which has four tables and I want to get these four tables details in single view.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this, 
1. Download FMDB files.
2. Add into your project.
3. Read path into your viewController.m

Follow the instruction on the website, if problem then feel free to contact.

link : `https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can go with any sqlite wrappers written in objective-c.

I will suggest [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) because it is very widely used and easy to learn as well.