# Use SQLite database in iPhone iOS 5 apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

Still am using `Coredata framework` for iPhone applications. I want switch to use `SQLite database` in my applications. I know something basics in MySQL queries. Is our SQLite is related to MySQL or different? And also how we can integrate `SQLite into XCode 4.2` and iPhone applications? I want to read something basics regarding SQLite database i used Google for Study material but, can't get an exact one. And also i have visited `W3Schools.com there they provided SQL queries`. I started my study with there.

Can anyone please suggest how to implement SQLite in our iPhone projects? Where to learn about SQLite databse? Which version of SQLite current we are using in iOS 5?

Comment: Thank you my friends. I must thank you all for your spot answers. I will use all your answers. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add sqlite3 lib to your project:

1. Select the target in your project setting page.
2. Click 'Build phases' tab,
3. Unfold 'Link binary with library',
4. Click '+',
5. Add sqlite to your target.

Then you can use the C API for sqlite.

There are [Objective-C wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640885/best-cocoa-objective-c-wrapper-library-for-sqlite-on-iphone) as well.